# Unable to cast to child object type from parent type

Tags: c#

I have 2 class Child and Parent described like below

```
class Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

class Child<T> : Parent
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

and I declare a parent object like this

```
Parent p = new Parent() { Name = "NMH", Number = 10 };
```

When I cast object p to a type of Children type by using

```
p as Children<T>
```

then it returns null

in my cast above, I just want to leave Data as default (null)

So could anyone explain why I can't cast like that? and tell me the solution

Comment: `p as Children<T>` you can't do  this. The parent _isn't_ the child.

Comment: `Parent p = new P()` is invalid declaration

Comment: Obviously, `T` is not a type so you can't do that, try something like `if (p is Children<int> c) { /* ... */ }`.

Comment: @MattBurland, but you still cast from object to other type, because all of them inherit object, or cast FormatException to Exception because FormatException inherits Exception, ...

Comment: You can cast from up from a child class to the parent, but not from a parent to the child if the object was instantiated as the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, C# doesn't let you cast in that direction.
I wish it would.

This will probably meet your needs.
It involves doing a clone as some of the comments have suggested.
(I'm doing a back and forth Json conversion. There are more efficient ways.)

```
class Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public T CloneAs<T>() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this));
}

class Child<T> : Parent
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

var p = new Parent { Name = "NMH", Number = 10 };
var child = p.CloneAs<Child<int>>();
```

Comment: When you say "cast in that direction", I believe you were saying that C sharp doesn't allow user defined conversion operators within a hierarchy. If so, can you clarify that. This is a good answer but it's worded a little vaguely.

Comment: That is a quick and dirty way to do it. Better to just have a copy constructor

Comment: it's inconvenience but it resolve my problem. could you tell me the reason why I couldn't cast as I did above